# Query not assigned into the variable / Not going into the condition

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, loops, if-statement

I was doing this code for my project and it seems that I can't get the values of the query into $currentRow. All that saved into the variable $currentrow is 22 which is the number rows in the database. I want to have access to all the query results. Please help. Here's the code.

```
public function getBSIConfig(){
    $conn = oci_connect("472proj","system","//localhost/XE");
    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT conf_id, conf_key, conf_value FROM bsi_configure");
    oci_execute($sql);
    echo "0";
    while($currentRow = oci_fetch_all($sql,$res)){
        echo "1.5";
        echo $currentRow;
        if($currentRow["conf_key"]){
        echo "1";
            if($currentRow["conf_value"]){
                $this->config[trim($currentRow["conf_key"])] = trim($currentRow["conf_value"]);
                echo "2";
            }else{
                $this->config[trim($currentRow["conf_key"])] = false;
                echo "3";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is only:

0

1.5

22

Comment: I've never used `oci_fetch_all` but wouldn't `fetch_all` give you an array with all the rows? So I'd think you'd `foreach` the array after assigning it; e.g. no `while`.

Answer (score 1):

The results from this function are stored in the 2nd argument, rather than returned directly. See if this works for you:

```
$results = array();
$numResults = oci_fetch_all($sql, $results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result["conf_key"]) {
        // etc ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php , you might get an idea what's wrong.